# multi mySQL driven web site

Tags: java, php

I have database driven web site that needs more than one MySQL Sever to handle the expected demand

I also need to implement back up system (of some type) to keep data safe.

I'm using java but that that’s not critical

What options are available to me from projects out their

I'm thinking of daisy chaining project with the MYSQL server's somehow and then when one is busy go to the next and they all be written data to. I know they can measure time used they must be able to measure when they are in use.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into clustering.

http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/

Comment: Yes thats just it. I'm just new and finding my feet. And cloud just uses way to many gigs to be pratical. Thanks.

Comment: Cluster != cloud. You can cluster 2 computers (or virtual instances on one machine). You use the cluster as one MySQL instance, so your application doesn't see that it is multiple machines. As far as data redundancy goes, the clustering has it built in with automatic recovery and fail-over and supports replication. If you're going to already have multiple servers, I would seriously consider a clustered solution (cloud or not).

Comment: yes I get to get it going and use it that I can ask questions to my needs first. Thanks for advice its realy good.

Answer (score 0):

How about deploying a Cluster in the cloud?

http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2009/public/schedule/detail/6912

Comment: as I said data cost is way to high to do so.

Comment: A remote database is no more complicated than DB in the computer, more expensive top operate, slower access time.............  Please comment when you know your subject. stupid stupid stupid

Comment: Can I be blocked through my user account some how. is their part of the ODBC that needs to be set to everyone user accounts